# How to excute JSTL code when we store in database

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, tiles

I'm using Spring and tiles

I'm storing JSTL code Into database.

When user logs in, it fetches the time and stores into session and puts this session value in JSP page but JSTL tag is not executed

for ex.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```

page output is

Item 1
   Item 2
   Item 3
   Item 4
   Item 5

but my output is

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: How are you load this code in jsp page?

Comment: <c:out value="${head}"></c:out>

head is session varible

Answer (score 1):

Any JSP file when the file is modified and recompiled web container detects, but this is definitely the wrong approach ... As for saving HTML templates database and process them, accept them to JSP.

Answer (score 0):

same problem wher you explain , that was not possible with the jstl to temple or directly from string to code in jsp page,
 once you will done only if you will use another jsp age which create load time more than current execution time, its better way to load using session every time and not store the database value

Comment: JSP files are "compiled" and transformed to a Java class file, so each value received by a JSP is just data, and cannot be added as part of the source code